# Extend 48 hour time limit for new member activation codes

Tags: members, activation

I have had a client complain after receiving "several emails a month" from new members getting the "invalid activation request" error after clicking the link in their activation email after signing up.

I think this is because they've left it longer than the 48 hours default time limit that each activation code is valid for.

Is there a straightforward way to increase this time limit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that I'm not 100% positive that this is correct, but for EE2 have a look at this file:
`/system/expressionengine/modules/member/mod.member_register.php`

The Member Self Activation method starts on line 743 
`public function activate_member()`

around line 799:
`$expire = time() - (60*60*48);`
this is a comparison on the current time minus two days.
It is comparing against pending members held in the exp_mailing_list_queue table

You may be able to modify the expire comparison to fit your needs, but I have not tested this to confirm.  Please remember that if you do make changes to the above codes, that they may be overwritten by future updates.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think you probably meant to say the file is `mod.member_register.php` not `mod.member_auth.php`. I've amended line 799 as you suggest. Cheers.

Comment: Oops.  My mistake.  I had multiple files open at the same time and noted the wrong one.  Sorry about that.  I've edited my answer with the correct filename.  Thanks for pointing it out.